# What are the scenarios that cause the compiler to emit spurious warnings?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

I sometimes read such comment by previous developers inside the source code:

```
// and this is to make compiler stop crying
```

I think with C/C++ it's typical that something you are doing practically legal, but still compiler sees it as illegal.

Is there a list of the scenarios that cause the compiler to emit spurious warnings?

Comment: It is to quiet warnings.

Comment: Compilers warn about things that are formally legal, but they believe might be a mistake anyway, like `if (i = 0)`.

Comment: I don't see why this has been closed.  The question is perfectly explicable and answerable.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Bo Persson, I am not talking about the normal compiler warnings; those are in fact useful. Unfortunately, I cannot put an answer, otherwise, I could have put one scenario.

Comment: "Can we have a list of X" is not answerable.

Comment: I'm with Bo Persson on this. There's no way you can get a list of all possible reasons why someone might put this comment in. And if you wanted to put in a scenario, it would go in the _question_, not an answer.

Comment: @Bo Persson, I have removed that line from my question. I wrote it because I have seen such question asked in SO. (e.g. list of undefined behavior, list of the way memory leak etc.)

Comment: @iammilind: Now it's not even a _question_. You're just saying that people sometimes put comments like that.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Sure it is - the question asks if it is possible to have an exhaustive list (the "exhaustive" part is implied, since otherwise the answer is obviously and trivially "yes", by just listing one case).  (The answer is "No", because compilers are allowed to warn about anything they want to).

Comment: @Nicol, The heading of the post already asks the right question which was modified by @caf.

Comment: @caf: OK, it's a question. Whether an exhaustive list exists however is not a _useful_ question.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I think that's entirely subjective.  The fact that C compilers can and do emit warnings for whatever completely legal code they want to is far from obvious.  I think there is also a useful discussion to be had about the cases in which the change to supress the warning is actually making the code correct (when it wasn't before).

Comment: @caf: read the question: that's _not_ what's being asked here. The question is, "What are the scenarios that cause the compiler to emit spurious warnings?" The only answer to this question is a list; it is not a discussion about what cases might exist or whatever. And even if that _were_ the question, that kind of discussion should probably take place on Programmers, not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: In my view, the answer "Such a list can't be created, and here's why:" makes it a completely useful question and answer pair.  The most useful answers here are the ones that provide a fuller discussion of the issues surrounding the question, rather than a robotically precise answer.  I feel that some people are far too quick to invoke the Close Hammer, and that Wikipedia-style lawyering is starting to take hold.  Anyway, I have now said my piece - if I notice that the question is reopened, I'll provide an answer, if not, so be it.

Comment: The core issue is the definition of "spurious". A warning indicates that you're doing something the compiler-writer believes is correlated with programming errors. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: List of warning depends on the compiler, and the compiler's version. I bet the list is huge, therefore voting to close

Comment: @VJo, I think this is going around in circles... there has to be some common ones that has irked us all... I think that this should be moved to Programmers though...

Comment: @VJo, IMHO `warning != spurious warning` as @caf suggested.

Comment: @iammalind: so IYO, which warning is never spurious, and therefore can be omitted from the list? Or are you asking only for warnings which are *always* spurious (arguably compiler bugs)?

Comment: @Steve Right. Sounds like the question asks for a list of compiler bugs, which again depends on the compiler, it's version, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no definitive list of such warnings, because the C standard does not disallow a conforming compiler from emitting warnings or diagnostic messages for legal code.  Each C compiler therefore has its own list of warnings, some of which can trigger on perfectly correct, perfectly legal code (the canonical example of this is a function with an argument that is never used).

This means that code change to suppress such warnings are usually aimed at a specific compiler (and perhaps even a specific version of that compiler) - and often discovered by trial-and-error rather than anticipated in advance.

Sometimes, however, such a code modification is actually making the code correct - the compiler diagnostic being suppressed is one required by the C standard.  The usual example of this is a cast required in an assignment - for example, an integer value cannot be assigned to a pointer object, but most compilers will emit a warning and compile the code anyway.  Adding a cast in this case silences the warning because it corrects the code - the warning is not really spurious at all.

Comment: Except that in C, the cast silences the warning but does not make the code correct! (particularly if `sizeof (int)` is 4 and `sizeof (void*)` is 8)

Comment: @pmg: In this case, by "correct" I mean a well-formed C program.  Whether it is semantically correct depends upon the C program in question.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious example that springs to my mind is that gcc warns for this:

```
while (i = somefunc())
```

And you suppress the warning with a particular easter-egg:

```
while ((i = somefunc()))
```

Assuming of course that the warning is incorrect, and that you didn't mean to write:

```
while (i == somefunc())
```

But it's highly dependent on your coding style what warnings you will trigger in error-free code. Some people, admittedly a small proportion of C programmers, would never make an assignment in a conditional in the first place, so for them this warning is not "spurious", because if they get it then it's *always* because of a typo for `==`.

Comment: And this is a fine example of why "spurious" is subjective and therefore why the question should be either closed or moved over to Programmers. How "spurious" this error is not only depends on your coding style, but whether or not the warning actually points out a common typo. You could add warnings about unreferenced arguments or variables to this list as well: do they catch typos or are they just annoying? Well, it depends; sometimes they do and sometimes they don't. I don't see anything productive coming out of this discussion, nor do I see a definitive answer being possible.

Comment: I wish there was a way I could turn off the suppression easter egg. I use a personal coding style that prohibits putting assignments in tests, not because they can't be done but rather because they're always unclear. Refactoring to take assignments out of conditionals increases code length (a negative) but increases clarity of intention a lot (a positive); the loss of freedom during development is compensated for by the ability to read it during support (especially if I'm tired that day).

Answer (score 2):

One of the cases where a programmer might write such a comment is where the problem that the compiler has identified is actually impossible, but it lies beyond the power of the compiler to determine that fact. An example:

```
int foo(char *barArg) {
    char *barPtr, *grillPtr;
    if (barArg == NULL) {
        grillPtr = malloc(...);      /* allocate */
        get_default_bar(grillPtr);   /* initialize */
        barPtr = grillPtr;
    } else {
        barPtr = barArg;
    }

    /* Some common block of processing that does _not_ refer to grillPtr,
     * does _not_ assign to barArg, and _updates_ barPtr. */

    if (barArg == NULL) {
        free(grillPtr);              /* <<<----- here */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, it's entirely possible that the compiler will issue a warning about a potentially-uninitialized variable (`grillPtr`) for the line with a `free()` because it can't work out that it could only have got there if the allocation/initialization had happened.

While a smarter compiler could understand the flow graph more completely and determine that the code was in fact safe, programmers are more likely to make things shut up by just setting `grillPtr` to `NULL` at the top of the function, so doing a very little extra work to achieve a warning-free build. (There are other ways to achieve the same effect, but it's easier to get it *right* at the point of declaration of the variable.)

In reality, it's arguably the case that this is indicating that some refactoring should be done instead, so that the function core is separated from all the hokey setup/cleanup code (and called from two branches, one which allocates, the other which lacks the variable). Alas, that's not always that easy to arrange in practice.

Comment: As noted, this is just one possibility. There are loads of others, and they evolve over time as compilers change. Also, just because the warning is wrong in this case doesn't mean it is always wrong: the programmer really does have to work it out themselves.

Comment: This is a somewhat dubious case. Just initialize grillPtr to NULL, allocate if needed, and at the end simply `free(grillPtr)`. No test needed, especially a backhanded test on barArg, and definitely no `// and this is to make compiler stop crying`. Assuming you have a compiler that was written in this millennium, the days when `free(NULL)` croaked are long gone.

Comment: Nice example, I have come across this many times.

Comment: @David: There are obvious extensions to this where what you write is non-useful (e.g., a malloced array of malloced structures). They're just a lot more code for something less clear _for instruction purposes_. This sort of thing does crop up in practice, especially with more complex decision flows (and refactoring can have other issues, but they're largely off-topic for this question).